# how to insert data in database and get data from database

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

I am new on iPhone development. I am making an app, using sqlite3 for database. I create my tables with sqlite3 manager 3.9.5 and write code copy database in appdelegete.m file and database copy successfully.

I insert data in database and insertion takes place successfully with primary key but when I access data from database, it sends null and if I open my database and open my tables they do not show the data I entered in table. Here is my code to insert data and get data from database.

```
- (IBAction)addrecord:(id)sender {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ebirthdaydatabase.sqlite"];
        if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {


            const char *sqlStatement = "insert into Name(name) VALUES(?)";
            sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;                
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
                NSLog(@"name.text :%@",name.text);

                sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 1, [name.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
//                ShowContactsViewController *contact = [[ShowContactsViewController alloc]init];
//                contact.username = name.text;
//                [contact addarray:contact];

            }

            if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) != SQLITE_DONE ) {
                NSLog( @"Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database) );
            } else {
                NSLog( @"Insert into row id = %lld", sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database));
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

        sqlite3_close(database);
        }

 sqlite3 *database;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ebirthdaydatabase.sqlite"];

    NSLog(@"%@",path);
    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        const char *sql = "select name from Name";
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

            while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                //                NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
                //                Coffee *coffeeObj = [[Coffee alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
                ShowContactsViewController *contact=[[ShowContactsViewController alloc]init];

                char *localityChars =( char *)sqlite3_column_name(selectstmt, 0);

                if (localityChars ==NULL)
                    contact.username = nil;
                else
                    contact.username = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: localityChars];

                //contact.username = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];
                NSLog(@"%@",username);

                [showcontact addObject:contact];
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to use some managers if you can't fix yours issue. for example https://github.com/misato/SQLiteManager4iOS

Answer (score 0):

The `sqlite3_column_name()` function will return the name of the column, not the contents.  You want `sqlite3_column_text()` instead.